# Is it possible for this function to be lower bounded by another function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given a **symmetric** $N\times N$ matrix $A=\{a_{ij}\}$, satisfies:

(1) The diagonal elements are 1, i.e. $a_{ii}=1$; Other elements $a_{ij}=1$ or $0$.

(2) The number of non-zero non-diagonal elements is positive, that means, it is not possible that all non-diagonal elements are zeros.

Let $E_A(\vec{\theta})=\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}(1-\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j))$, where $\theta_i\in(0,2\pi], \forall i\in\{1,\cdots,N\}$. It can be seen from condition that $E_A$ is positive.

Can we find another **symmetric** matrix $B=\{b_{ij}\}$, satisfying (1) and (2) and the following condition (3),

(3) When $i\neq j$, if $a_{ij}=1$ then $b_{ij}=0$.

such that
$$E_B\leq E_A,$$
in which $E_B(\vec{\theta})=\sum_{i,j}b_{ij}(1-\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j))$?

Answer (score 1):

There must exist an $A$ s.t. no such $B$ exist. Consider the function
$$
F: \{\text{$N\times N$ 0-1 matrices}\}\times [0, 2\pi]^n,\quad (A, \theta)\mapsto E_A(\theta),
$$
The domain of $F$ is compact and $F$ is continuous, so $F$ achieves a maximun.